# PHP cannot connect to Postgres - Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: php, postgresql

My current set up is CentOS 7, with Postgres 9.2 and PHP 5.4.

I am moving an existing site onto a new server and the connection code used is

```
pg_connect(dbname=database user=postgres)
```

(Above i have removed the original database name as irrelevant to this issue). When i look at the apache logs i see code fails with error;

```
PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory\n\tIs the server running locally and accepting\n\tconnections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I am accessing the server remotely and have phpPgAdmin working fine on it, if i include `host=localhost` in my connection string then it all works fine. My question is how can I get it working without having to include the host in the connection string, from all documentation i can find it is optional and therefore if blank defaults to localhost (which is what i want).

Problem is the setup i am moving uses pg_connect a lot and never has the host specified. It would mean changing almost every page to include this in every connection string.

I have tried changing permissions on pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf to 777 without any luck. I have tried `ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`as suggested in many questions on here without luck and SELinux is set to permissive but just in case i also did `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

My pg_hba.conf looks like

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          IP-MASK      METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                                                 trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1             255.255.255.255   trust
host    all         all         192.168.7.0           255.255.255.0     trust
host    all         all         192.168.8.0           255.255.255.0     trust
host    all         all         192.16.10.0           255.255.255.0     trust
host    all         all         10.0.10.0             255.255.255.0     trust
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0 trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128                                 trust
```

My postgresql.conf includes

```
max_connections = 120
listen_addresses = ‘*’
port = 5432
```

php code being loaded is sadly on my test page it is simply 
`$second = pg_connect(dbname=database user=postgres) or die(cannot connect again)` if changed to `$second = pg_connect(host=localhost dbname=database user=postgres) or die(cannot connect again)` it works fine.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to connect? Don't forget to redact the username password. Usually you can specify which local socket to connect to, or use TCP instead.

Comment: sadly on my test page it is simply $second = pg_connect(dbname=database user=postgres) or die(cannot connect again) if changed to $second = pg_connect(host=localhost dbname=database user=postgres) or die(cannot connect again)  it works fine.

Comment: The `host=localhost` part forces TCP. If that's acceptable, there's your answer.

Comment: yes i appreciate that, however it was never needed in the connection string before as was optional. Which is why I am trying to find a setting that requires changing instead of going through and changing every page using pg_connect()

Comment: If you're having to change "every page" then you've got a structural problem in your code. You really should have a unified connection class where this is all defined *once* and once only. Include that as required. Even better, pick a framework that suits your style and needs and use that to interact with your database. The 1990s style of piles and piles of independent PHP scripts is extremely messy and hard to maintain for reasons that you're already observing.

Comment: thank you, i will start to look into setting up a class. Have you any idea why my connection string no longer works without the host specified? It is an old system i am moving so quite possibly many things that can now be unified.